# Installing several workspaced npm (yarn) packages from a git repository

Tags: yarn-workspaces, rescript

I have two repositories.  The first one contains is a monorepo with two packages:

```
   - bsconfig.json
   - package.json
   - packages/
     - transaction/
       - package.json
       - transaction.js
     - reindexed/
       - package.json
       - src/
         - IDB.res
         - ReIndexed.res
```

The `packages/reindexed` actually depends on `packages/transaction`.  The contents of `packages/transaction/packages.json` is like this (fragment):

```json
{
  "name": "@kaiko-internal/transaction",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "transaction.js"
}
```

The file `packages/reindexed/package.json` is more or less like this:

```json
{
  "name": "@kaiko/reindexed",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "esbuild": "^0.12.9",
    "qunit": "^2.16.0",
    "rescript": "^9.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@kaiko-internal/transaction": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Notice the second project uses ReScript as the main language and includes this line:

```
@module("@kaiko-internal/transaction") external transaction: 'a = "default"
```

(The file `transaction.js` is a little hard to write in ReScript at the moment)

Now in a second project I depend on `@kaiko/reindexed` like this:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@kaiko/reindexed": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:kaiko-systems/ReIndexed.git#workspaces"
   }
}
```

But when I run `yarn` and try to compile this project I'm not getting the proper `@kaiko/reindexed` and its dependency and it basically fails to install the `@kaiko-internal/transaction`, i.e `import * from '@kaiko-internal/transaction';` fails.

Is there a way to install several dependencies from a workspaced monorepo?

Comment: Did you try this doc: https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/build-pinned-dependencies?

Comment: We decided to avoid the monorepo and ported the `transaction.js` to ReScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can add transaction as local package:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@kaiko-internal/transaction": "file:../transaction"
  }
```

After you need to do `yarn install` or `npm install`
And then you will have link in node_modules to the transaction